# How To Put Back Button in Fragment Class in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to put back button on Fragment class. I want to put back button on left ShoppingMazza text .
[image]

nav_drawer_row.xml:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/log" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="shopByCategory"
            android:text="Shop By Category"/>

    <!--   <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/imageView1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/electronic1" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:text="Hello" />

       </RelativeLayout>  -->


       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <ImageView
               android:paddingLeft="60dp"
               android:id="@+id/imageView1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/electronic1" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Electronic"/>


       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="60dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/fashion" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingTop="10dp"
               android:paddingBottom="10dp"
               android:textSize="15dp"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:text="Fashion &amp; Lifestyle "/>



       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="25dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/deal" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="deal"
            android:text="@string/today_deals"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="25dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView4"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/track" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="home"
            android:text="@string/track_your_order"/>


       </RelativeLayout>


       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="25dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView5"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/track" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="legal"
            android:text="@string/legal"/>

       </RelativeLayout>


       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="25dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView6"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/rate1" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/rate_this_app"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="25dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView7"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/query" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="query"
            android:text="@string/any_other_query"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="25dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView8"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView8"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/follow_us_on_twitter"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:paddingLeft="25dp"
           android:id="@+id/imageView9"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/fb" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView9"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/follow_us_on_facebook"/>

       </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>



 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When click on back button drawer layout is closed.Anyone can hep me how i solved my problem.

Comment: You can use other slider for this instand of put back button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think that it is very strange to put a back button here.because you can close drawer by slide it .But any way just put your back button like this .


<RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="60dp">

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/electronic1" />


             <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />


           </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I know this is strange but client say so i have require. any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

First put a back button here is a bad idea, try to take a look to the google layout design.

But for your pb, you wants help for the layout ? 
in your case juste create an horizontal Linear Layout, and add your button and then your image.

For the close operation we lack of information. Does you want to close the activity ? 
does you want to go back to the main fragment ?

I'm a bit confused cauz it seems that you never touched android development.